# How do I stop Surface from doing System Update?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Disabled windows updates and windows update service, how do I stop the Surface from trying to do this update?

The battery is toast so windows won't let it get to its next steps I must be able to disable this somewhere?
It's preventing me from being able to install another OS because it just goes to this on startup

[image: Startup screen]

Comment: Are you saying you get this screen as soon as you turn the surface on? You said you're not able to install a different OS because of this, which doesn't really make sense given the rest of your question. Could you please clarify things?